# ListView using custom Adapter. Button to remove a child in a Firebase Database

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android developement and I'm having a hard time making my listView work with FirebaseDatabase.

I have a ListView, in which each item, representing an object in my FirebaseDatabase, have a remove button. What I want to do is, when the user clicks on the button, delete this entry from the online database. If I'm not mistaken, that should trigger the onChildRemoved() callback method in the Activity which contains the ListView, and therefore, I'll have to update the ListView there (that is already taken care of)

I tried implementing setOnClickListener in my Adapter, but I can't make it work. Does one of you know how to do this ?

Side question: I used the push() method to add my Objects to the database. Since the key is needed to remove the Object, I figured that adding a pushId member to the said object was the easiest method to keep track of it. I'd just like to know if this logic makes sense or not.

If any of this seems strange to you, just tell me. I'm aware of the possibility of me doing this all wrong and I'd like to make it the right way !

Comment: There are multiple questions listed here. It is best practice to break out your questions into separate posts. You can have an OnItemClickListener in a ListView. Storing a key with an object is okay. You can also call getKey to get the key for a particular object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is sort of a mini-project, but I made some code for you that hopefully helps.

The code below makes a sample arraylist of "thingy" objects. A Thingy object has a name (eg: box,toy,cat) and UID field (produced using the push() method you mentioned you're using). The list of Thingy objects are then set to the FirebaseDatabase root node (ref) with their labels being their UID. While you probably have this code written, we'll use this code block as an example.

```
    // a root database reference
    DatabaseReference ref =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RootNode");

    // sample arraylist of objects
    // Thingy objects have a type and UID field
    ArrayList<Thingy> thingyList = new ArrayList();
    thingyList.add(new Thingy("box",ref.push().getKey()));
    thingyList.add(new Thingy("toy",ref.push().getKey()));
    thingyList.add(new Thingy("cat",ref.push().getKey()));

    // set all Thingy objects in thingyList to your root node
    // under the label that is the thingy's UID
    for (Thingy x : thingyList) {
        ref.child(x.getUID()).setValue(x);
    }

    // setup the adapter and listview
    // R.id.remove_item is an xml layout that contains
    //     a textview and a remove button
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter( this, R.layout.remove_item, thingyList);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.removeListView);
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Then in order to use your adapter to use remove buttons to delete the thingy objects from your FirebaseDatabase, you can attach an onClickListener to each Button for every item. Then use remove() to fully delete the object from the database.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList> {
private Context context;
private int resource;
private ArrayList arrayList;

private DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RootNode");


public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList arrayList) {
    super(context, resource, arrayList);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView type;
    Button removeButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        viewHolder.type = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.type);
        viewHolder.removeButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Thingy x = (Thingy) arrayList.get(position);

    viewHolder.type.setText(x.getType());
    viewHolder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ref.child(x.getUID()).removeValue();
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Attaching a listener to every item can be expensive, so if you have a large list of objects, performance may drop. However, this is the implementation for using a listener in the adapter, and working with adapters can become tricky when your listview items become more complicated. So maybe as you learn more and more android, you can find a more efficient way of removing items in your project.

As for your other questions:
Yes, onChildRemoved will be called. However, it doesnt make sense to update listviews from onChildRemoved. If a user deletes an item, onClick should do the deleting. As for other users who access the same database, they should simply read the database at the time their app tries to create the listview. Using onChildRemoved makes sense only if you need to broadcast some type of alert to all other users that something has happened.

Using push() is an easy and safe way to create unique id's (UID in my code) that can be used to reference objects throughout your project. While you can use inheritance to separate objects from their UID's (have a parent class that only holds id's and use setValue on the child class object), I very often just include the UID in the objects instance fields and then get the UID when sending them to the database.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for this code sample, it's definitely helping ! However, as I see why I shouldn't update listviews from onChildRemoved, it makes me wonder how I should handle the data retrieval. Should I use addListenerForSingleValueEvent() to retrieve my data each time the user goes to the activity containing the ListView, and handle the rest locally ? I also need the user to be able to click on the items to get more informations about it, am I not wrong saying that using this approach, I'll also have to handle the user clicking  on an unexisting item ?

Comment: If your activity is not live, addListenerForSingleValueEvent() works great. If your activity is live (sounds like it is), using child events does make sense since you're "alerting" other users realtime, but its more costly and can make the UX rough if not well handled. At this point, its less about what's right and more using your discretion as to what works and is more efficient. Just make sure your FirebaseDB tree is very shallow and lightweight (eg: dont store images 5 levels deep under an objects root node) otherwise every snapshot of your objects that you get will overloaded with data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add all firebase key into map key and then based on key you all get all value and display list . Once remove call onChildRemove() pass key and do notifydatasetchaged .so it would be delete it fromm your list. and if you wanted to delete from firebase just pass null.Might be following code help you.

@Override

```
public void onChildAdded(Object listenerId,String key,EventObject value) {
    hashMapObject.put(key, value);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) getAdapter();
    adapter.add(hashMapObject.size()-1, value);
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(Object listenerId, String key, EventObject value) {
    int index = -1;
    for(String _key : hashMapObject.keySet()){
        index++;
        if(_key.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
            hashMapObject.put(key, value);
            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) getAdapter();
            adapter.update(index, value);
            break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(Object listenerId, String key) {
    int index = -1;
    for(String _key : hashMapObject.keySet()){
        index++;
        if(_key.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
            hashMapObject.remove(key);
            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = (RecyclerViewAdapter) getAdapter();
            adapter.remove(index);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```